# what happens if i don't specify the collection name in Corb

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-corb

I have a corb script to run node replace on the xml files.

If I don't specify the collection, will it remove the documents from the existing collections?

Comment: are you asking about the `xdmp:node-replace()` method, or do you mean if you were to use `xdmp:document-insert()` to "update" a document? There is no collection parameter for node-replace().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are altering the document with [`xdmp:node-replace()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace?q=node-replace), then the document will remain in it's collections and you do not need to worry about setting/adding it back.

If you are using [`xdmp:document-insert()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert) to replace the document at the current URI, then you do need to specify the collection(s), otherwise it will be removed from the existing collections.

However, you can use [`xdmp:document-get-collections()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get-collections) to retrieve the sequence of collections for the URI and use it for the 4th parameter of `xdmp:document-insert()`

```
xdmp:document-insert($URI, $doc, (), xdmp:document-get-collections($URI))
```

Comment: Thanks @mads-hansen. I am just replacing a node, so i will skip the collections

Answer (score 0):

Its better to provide an empty collection value, while doing the node-replace so it doesn't alter the existing collections of the document. Not defining this attribute is throwing errors while running the script.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If calling xdmp:node-replace(), there is no parameter for collections. If calling xdmp:document-insert(), not providing collections (omitting the parameter) will put the document into the user's default collections; specifying no collections (empty sequence) will make the document be in no collections. Mads answer ought to be accepted.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Cassel. xdmp:node-replace has no collection options, but specifying the collection in the corb scripts is where i had issue.